# Magento 2 : How to remove my account navigation links?

Tags: magento2, customer, xml

How to remove **Stored payment method** links from the navigation menu on customer account page?

[image]

Comment: could u share us screenshot please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove by add this code to your theme default.xml file.

```
<referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-credit-cards-link" remove="true"/>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can remove all links using the code below, just add a file:

**app/design/frontend/[Namespace]/[Theme]/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <!-- Remove unwanted account navigation links -->
        <!-- Put this file in: app/design/frontend/[Namespace]/[Theme]/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml -->

        <!-- Store credit -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-customer-balance-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Downloadable product link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-downloadable-products-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Subscription link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-newsletter-subscriptions-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Billing agreement link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-billing-agreements-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Product review link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-product-reviews-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- My credit card link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-credit-cards-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Account link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-account-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Account edit link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-account-edit-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Address link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-address-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Orders link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-orders-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Wish list link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-wish-list-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Gift card link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-gift-card-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Order by SKU -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-checkout-sku-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Gift registry -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-giftregistry-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Reward points -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-reward-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Invitation -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-magento-invitation-link" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to your layout file from your custom module for example:

Here i am giving you sample example:

go to layout file

**Layout handle content:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-wish-list-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-billing-agreements-link" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: only remove store payment method

Comment: just i am giving u sample example